# How do I make this program work in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to search an excel file and return the price of the corresponding search. It runs just file in the Command Prompt, but does not when I try to run it in the IDE PyCharm.

I believe that it isn't doing anything with the line

```
df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Test.xls')
print("EXIT to end")
PN = input('Enter PN: ')
Number = df['Part Number'] == PN
df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']]
```

This should provide an output that gives me the Part number and Price but instead it just ends and doesn't return anything where as in the Command Prompt it was returning the correct values.

Comment: adding print ?  ?

Comment: Did you try to add a `print()` statement? So `df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']]` would be `print(df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']])`. If I remember correctly, PyCharm might output/print the last line of code even without any explicit `print()` statement...

Comment: print(df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']]) was the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `print()` statement at the last line of code in order to get the desired output printed.

The line

```
df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']]
```

will become

```
print(df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']])
```

---

*Note: Summarized solutions from comments to ensure question can be marked as solved.*